# Python:Error al eliminar elementos de una lista

Tags: python

Estoy intentando eliminar aquellos elementos que tienen un valor igual o superior a 5.
Para ello ejecuté este código:

```
    asignaturas=['Matemáticas','Física','Química', 'Historia', 'Lengua']
    for i in asignaturas:
            notas=float(input(f'¿qué nota tienes en {i}?:'))
            if notas >= 5:
                asignaturas.remove(i)
    print(asignaturas)
```

Al darle el valor 4 a todas funciona correctamente, sin embargo cuando les doy valor 5 solo me pregunta por los elementos 1,3 y 5 de la lista. ¿Cuál es mi error?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Solución de una línea `asignaturas = list(filter(lambda i: int(input(f'¿qué nota tienes en {i}?:')) < 5, asignaturas))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es por como funciona el método `.remove()` este método se ejecuta en la propia lista, por lo tanto tu lista va disminuyendo de tamaño conforme se ejecuta el `for`.

Lo que te está sucediendo es lo siguiente:

- Iniciamos el `for` con el primer valor `Matemáticas` y le ponemos un cinco
- Entra en el `if` y borra el primer valor de nuestra lista `asignaturas`
- El primer valor pasa a ser ahora `Física`
- Vamos a por la segunda iteración, el bucle `for` sabe que ya ha consumido la posición 0 de la lista, la siguiente es la posición 1. Al haber cambiar nuestra lista durante la ejecución, la posición uno ahora es `Química` mientras que la cero es `Física`, ya que `Matemáticas` se eliminó.

Hay varias formas de evitar esto, usando otro método, otro búcle, etc. En este caso, yo opto por la más sencilla que es crearte una lista que copie la a `asignaturas` y hacer en ella los cambios para después imprimirla, tu código quedaría así:

```
asignaturas=['Matemáticas','Física','Química', 'Historia', 'Lengua']
asignaturas_2 = asignaturas[:]
for i in asignaturas:
        notas=float(input(f'¿qué nota tienes en {i}?:'))
        print(asignaturas)
        if notas >= 5:
            asignaturas_2.remove(i)
print(asignaturas_2)
```

Lo importante es que entiendas lo que está sucediendo, una vez lo sabes ¡Ya puedes crear las soluciones que quieras!

Comment: Tiene toda la lógica, muchisimas gracias, funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 2):

Por completar las soluciones ya dadas (que son perfectamente válidas), muestro otro enfoque típico que es, en lugar de destruir crear.

Es decir, en lugar de partir de una lista con todo para ir eliminando lo que no quieres, partimos de una lista vacía a la que vamos agregando lo que quieres (en este caso, las asignaturas suspensas). Sería así:

```
asignaturas=['Matemáticas','Física','Química', 'Historia', 'Lengua']
suspensas = []

for i in asignaturas:
    notas=float(input(f'¿qué nota tienes en {i}?:'))
    if notas < 5:
        suspensas.append(i)

print(suspensas)
```